# Save and restore local variables in Hamilton C Shell

Tags: shell, csh

I try to save all the variable state at a point in a file and restore all the saved variable when needed. I don't see how to achieve the `RestoreState` and keeping the variable type, maybe someone has already done that ?

```sh
# script.csh
local a,b

@ a = 1
@ b = "hello"

proc SaveState ()
    local > backup.txt
endproc # SaveState

proc RestoreState ()
    # If file backup.txt exists
    if (-e backup.txt) then
        echo -- "----- Restore saved state -----"
    end # if
endproc # RestoreState

SaveState
@ b = "world"
RestoreState
# list variables, should print 1 and "hello"
local
```

**Edit**: `"1" == 1` so it is not necessary to keep variable type

Comment: I know the "traditional" C-Shell supports `source file` (and I think `. file`) , wouldn't that work for restoring saved state? Good luck.

Comment: (Oh, "keeping the variable type", no idea, Good luck !/-: )

Comment: If you get really desperate, `awk` returns `2` when it does a division by zero, so `awk 'END{x="abc" ; print "x="x ; print 30/x }' /dev/null` could be used to decide between strings and numbers. Hmm, but the way I would do something like that with `bash/ksh` would be to use a `case` statement. Where did you find a system w Hamilton? Good luck!

Comment: Thank for the "Good luck", But I just testing some things, and the variable type is not an obligation in a way that `"1" == 1` so it isn't a turn off, I'm going to take a look to `source file` i'll keep you in touch

Comment: Good bit of research on the `"1" == 1` thing! Not sure now if "standard" c-shell supports `source file`, but almost certain it does support `. file`. In `bash/ksh` where both exist, they are the same thing. So try `. file`. Good luck.

Comment: And thinking about Hamilton C-shell further, I'm sure the only reason I knew about it was from years of reading the `comp.unix.shell` internet newsgroup (maybe you are familiar with that idea ? (-; ) . That newsgroup is still active (if often overwhelmed with spam), but you might find archives you could search, or do a new post there and connect with other H-C-Shell users. (You can do it with google groups, but I think I read that "product" is on the endangered list). Do I need to send you the `csh-why-not` URL? (-;? Good luck!

Comment: @shellter, Solution found ;), Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by using sed and by saving the `backup.txt` file in a format that can be read by the `source` command:

```sh
proc SaveState ()
    local | sed 's/^^\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)[\t ]*\(.*\)$/@ \1 = "\2"/' > backup.txt
endproc # SaveState

proc RestoreState ()
    # If file backup.txt exists
    if (-e backup.txt) then
        source backup.txt
    end # if
endproc # RestoreState
```